# ZeroDivisionError- Unable to figure out what's wrong

Tags: python

I wrote the following code and its giving "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero" error

```
def squares(n, m):
  assert n>= 0 and m>= 0 and n+m > 0
  if n==0:
      c=m
  elif m==0:
      c=n
  else:
      c= squares(min(m,n), max(m,n)%min(m,n))
      
  return n*m/c*c
  
print(squares(10,6))
```

I am new to python and am still unable to figure the error please help.

Thankyou

Comment: if n and m are both 0 then c will equal 0. and you are using modulo, which will give 0 in every nth case, thus returning 0 for c. You should probably also explore try except blocks as well.

Comment: `min(m,n)` returns 0 when one of m, n equals zero; this causes division by 0 in '%' (modulo) operation..

Comment: @Alan wrong; if `n==m==0` then assertion (`n+m>0`) fails.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Oops, I missed the assertion, thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `c= squares(min(m,n), max(m,n)%min(m,n))` can set `c` to zero, and then you divide by `c` in the return statement.

Comment: Also I imagine your return expression is supposed to be `n*m/(c*c)`; otherwise you're dividing and then subsequently multiplying by `c`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, notice the line:

```
return n*m/c*c
```

this will return `0` if either of `n` and `m` is 0. According to this line:

```
c= squares(min(m,n), max(m,n)%min(m,n))
```

`c` could be `0`, resulting in `ZeroDivisionError` in the return line.